# How does Flutter FutureBuilder exactly work?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous

need something to be clear in my head but cannot find any clear answer:

Assuming a simple FutureBuilder like this:

```
    FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: _calculation, // a previously-obtained Future<String> or null
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.none:
        return Text('Press button to start.');
      case ConnectionState.active:
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return Text('Awaiting result...');
      case ConnectionState.done:
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        return Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}');
    }
    return null; // unreachable
  },
)
```

How are we passing from one case to another?

1- is the builder function called on a regular basis (ie every 10ms) and each time re-test the ConnectionState value?

2- Or is the builder function only called each time this ConnectionState value has changed?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly FutureBuilder is not really something that you should use for periodic calls, if you are planning for periodic calls or something, your should take a look at Streams and StreamBuilder. Here is a link to get you started :

Streams : https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-stream-basics-for-beginners-eda23e44e32f
StreamBuilder : https://medium.com/flutterdevs/stream-builder-in-flutter-ed5546d0fabc

Now that's out of the way, the builder function will only be called like twice, once before completion of your future function(i.e ConnectionState.waiting) and then once your Future function return the result(i.e ConnectionState.done).

You can get info about connectionStates here : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder/builder.html